# How to force my text to not break into lines in css?

Tags: html, css, autogrow

I have a div inside another fixed width div. I want inner div can grow horizontally until in can contain all of it's elements or texts in one line. doesn't matter to create a horizontal scroll bar. what should I do? this is my sample code:

```
<div style="width:400px;border:solid 1px red;">
    TEST TEXT
    <div style="border:solid 3px green;position:absolute;z-index:99;text-overflow:">
        TEST INSIDE TEST INSIDE TEST INSIDE TEST INSIDE TEST INSIDE
        TEST INSIDE TEST INSIDE TEST INSIDE TEST INSIDE TEST INSIDE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `white-space:nowrap;` - http://jsfiddle.net/uYKKy/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` for text to not break on white-spaces

Answer (score 2):

I will add the options in css of  text-overflow: ellipsis; with overflow: hidden; and white-space: nowrap;

if you use it this way:

```
h1{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You will get nice trim to overflow text.

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/Dbrvo)

[protip about triminng for text](https://coderwall.com/p/yxeiiw)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your trying to point out? Try to see the JSfiddle `code`
http://jsfiddle.net/uYKKy/1/

Comment: Not my answer but good point! I wanted whole page scrolls. but I like what you recommend me for future using :)